# I'm trying to reconstruct a table from an image which has hindi+english text using pytessaract

Tags: ocr, python-tesseract

This is the image[image] from which I am trying to extract data which is in hindi+english, using pytessaract and then I wish to reconstruct it back to an excel file with the same formatting

Firstly, the problem is that I can pass only one language(hindi in this case) to the pytessaract model so I get the result like this:
[image]
My code looks like this:

```
file = "./1.jpg"
text = []
# use pytesseract to read the text from the image 
img = cv2.imread(file)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
text.append(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="hin"))
# print(text)
# export
with open('temp.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.writelines(text)
```

I have two questions:

1. How do I read both english and hindi texts from this image i.e, how do I pass english and hindi as parameters to the `image_to_string()` method
2. Once I perform this ocr, how do I reconstruct the table and export that dataframe to excel file?